# regular expression to the following string

Tags: php

let me know I can use that expression to extract the url in the following code

```
<div class="bg-movie alpha omega">
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-7282" 
         title="CineMundo Tu Mejor Lugar El Caballero de la Noche Asciende" 
         src="http://www.cinemundo.cl/sitio/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/cinemundo_batman_el-caballero-de-la-noche-asciende_estrenos-2012.jpg" 
         alt="Película El Caballero de la Noche Asciende - Estrenos 2012" 
         width="117" height="173">
</div>
```

and come to this but I do not work well

```
preg_match_all('/<img [class="bg-movie alpha omega"]*src=["|\']([^"|\']+)/i', $html, $images);
```

Comment: Before you get swamped or closed, there is much discussion about NOT using regex to get data from HTML documents. The general consensus is to use [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) which is much safer and more reliable.

Comment: como esto? $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->loadHTML( file_get_contents($url) );
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
 return $xpath->query('//div[@class="bg-movie alpha omega"]/img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to force regular expressions do deal with all the weird edge cases when parsing HTML, you could just use PHP's built-in DOM library for parsing the HTML and getting the data you need:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();

$data = <<<EOD
<div class="bg-movie alpha omega">
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-7282"
         title="CineMundo Tu Mejor Lugar El Caballero de la Noche Asciende"
         src="http://www.cinemundo.cl/sitio/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/cinemundo_batman_el-caballero-de-la-noche-asciende_estrenos-2012.jpg"
         alt="Película El Caballero de la Noche Asciende - Estrenos 2012"
         width="117" height="173">
</div>
EOD;

$doc->loadHTML($data);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$result = $xpath->query('//img/@src');

foreach ($result as $srcAttr) {
    echo $srcAttr->value, "\n";
}
```

***EDIT:*** Here is an example loading a page from the website:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$url='http://www.cinemundo.cl/peliculas/batman-el-caballero-de-la-noche-asciende/';
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$result = $xpath->query('//div[@class="bg-movie alpha omega"]/img/@src');

foreach ($result as $srcAttr) {
    echo $srcAttr->value, "\n";
}
```

Comment: If you know there is only one element, there is no point in using foreach statement. It can be changed to **echo $result->item(0)->value;**

Comment: @Tim - Thanks! I was assuming he might want to get more than one URL off the same page (even though there was only one in the example), but your way makes more sense in the context of the example. I'm glad to see a consensus about using DOM rather than regexes!

Comment: if I replace the code with a website and in many link but guided me through the chain where class = "bg-alpha omega movie"> handed me the url

Comment: @Luisruiz - I'm glad you got it figured out!

Comment: se puede reemplazar por una url?

Comment: @Luisruiz - Check my edit above. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Gracias , pero no me funciona . quisiera poder mandarte el codigo completo para ver en que estoy fallando

Comment: @Luisruiz - I changed the example for loading the file from a URL. I just ran that code on my machine and it successfully finds the URL.

Comment: I do not write the url manually, the url I receive from a rss

like this    
$url = html_entity_decode($item->get_url ());

Comment: dejo el codigo completo https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QNaYetX9KWABia23-ZNijH6DtyLDnymyF9HnD3WVLgM/edit

Comment: You're using regular expressions to parse the XML? Try using the DOM library to pull the `link` nodes out of that RSS feed and maybe that will fix your problem.

Comment: el problema estoy recién en  esto de php y no entiendo mucho

Comment: Parsing the RSS feed and querying for `<link>` elements will be almost exactly the same as parsing HTML, but you'll use `load($url)` instead since it's XML. You just need to change the XPATH query slightly to extract the data you need, e.g. `'//item/link'` for all the links.

Answer (score 1):

As advised you should consider using PHP DOM library. Your code will be readable and reusable.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($html);
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```